# How to identify retried google cloud function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We want to deploy a cloud function with retries:

`gcloud function deploy somefunc --retry`

We want to identify functions that are being retried:

```
if execution_is_a_retry = True:
    ...
```

**How can we identify that a function is being retried?**

Is there some parameter in the context / event data?  Ideally we would also see the number of retries that have occurred.

I know that `execution_id` remains the same between the original run and a retry run but the only way to check that would be if the function writes the original id somewhere.  In that case, it's possible that the function could fail before successfully writing it's `execution_id` somewhere and then consequent retries would not be identified as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The retry invocation itself will not identify itself as a retry.  You will have to determine this yourself, based in your own record of the event ID passed in the context parameter.  If you see the same event ID more than once, you will know that your function was retried based on a prior failure.  *You won't know if the failure was because of your function, or something in Google's infrastructure.*

You can get the event ID for a background function using `context.eventID` as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters).

If you do enable retries, you should look into [making your function idempotent](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#make_retryable_background_functions_idempotent) so that you don't unnecessarily or harmfully repeat work that it previously did.  This will again require some record-keeping on your end to implement this correctly.

Comment: Thank you!  What do you recommend as the most robust method of record keeping for execution_id?  We are using Redis Memorystore but get transient ConnectionResetError on the global client object about once per day.

Comment: I can't recommend anything.  It depends on what you're comfortable with, how you need to scale, how much you're willing to pay, and now many more moving parts you want to add to your function.  You should be able to use Memorystore, but that will require the configuration of a VPC, as far as I've read: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-functions