# Google Cloud Function - Detect if retry occured

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

**My Setup**

I have a background `Google Cloud Function` that receives requests from a `PubSub` subscription. The function is written in `python3.8`.

I have enabled retries for the function. My function may fail with **memory exceeded** error.

**What I Wish to Accomplish**

I want to know if the request that the function received is a `retry`. I want to gracefully handle a case where the function has failed, so the second time that it will arrive I will handle it.

Using max delivery attempt and dead letter topic is not exactly what I want, because minimum number for `max_delivery_attempt` is 5. In that case my function may fail for 5 times before reaching the dead letter topic. I wish it to fail up to one time and then handle that case.

**The Question**

How can I know that a retry is being executed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify retried google cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328382/how-to-identify-retried-google-cloud-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  you can see in this page of [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1#receivedmessage), the delivery attempt field is:

- Only available when you pull a subscription, not when you plug your function directly on PubSub (it's a push subscription and wrapped in a special delivery package)
- Only populated if you set a deadletter topic on your subscription, else the valus is 0.

Therefore, if you need to track this value, I recommend you to keep a trace in an external database, firestore for example.